# PHP session_write_close does not have parallel requests execute at same time on hosting server

Tags: php, ajax

I am sending several requests (100 for example) with ajax.
I would like these time consuming requests to be treated in parallel on server side (PHP).
Therefore I am closing the session on PHP side before executing consuming time request.

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
ob_start();
ignore_user_abort(true);
session_write_close();
header("Content-Encoding: none");
header("Content-Length: 0");
header("Connection: close");
ob_end_flush();
flush();
// time consuming request
...
```

This works perfectly well in localhost, but on hosting server it acts as if I had not closed session: I just have 6 requests working at the same time.
Do you know what could explain this difference of behaviour between localhost and hosting server? How I could have theses requests run in parallel on hosting server?
Thanks!

Comment: What PHP version do you use into localhost and into hosting server?

Comment: Why do you want to close session to control parallel requests? 
Why don't you use a QUEUE service to control your process in backgroud?
If your problem is latence for many requests, so make a queue system for processing one by one request and after processing request by request, you do sending a message for your user by push notification, or update your session.

Comment: I am running PHP 5.4.3 in localhost and PHP 5.4.45 in hosting server

Answer (score 1):

What is probably happening is that the server has a [different session handler](http://php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php) configured (if it's a shared hosting provider, they probably have in-memory session storage to avoid heavy and expensive disk I/O). That means that the behavior of `session_write_close` may not always be what you expect.

If you want to execute several jobs in parallel, I would advise you to use **queues**, such as [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/), and avoid using session storage in the requests. Your AJAX script would push the job details to the queue, and a worker script running in command-line will be pulling these jobs from the queue and processing them. For the worker, you can use something like [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) or a recurring cronjob.

Comment: Thanks DfKimera. I am in deed using a shared hosting, however if I check phpinfo on my hosted website, "session.save_handler property" is set to "files". Any idea  which config I should check to know which behaviour I should expect from `session_write_close` ?

Comment: I just tested a workaround: I removed closing session code from my requester.php file and created a requesterProxy.php file which will call requester.php via curl with a very short timeout (`curl_setopt($ch, CURL_OPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 10)`). I make my Ajax call to requesterProxy.php instead of requester.php. I don't know if it is a very clean solution but it enables me to have my 100 requests exectued in parallel in my hosting server.